# React-Native DraweNavigator Localization/Translation

Tags: react-native, localization

I'm experimenting lastly with RN, and it seems as a pretty neat alternative to native development.

However, now I'm stuck with pretty silly problem: localization. I'm using this library: [ReactNativeLocalization](https://github.com/stefalda/ReactNativeLocalization).

It is pretty straightforward, and I adopted it in all my screens. I use it in combination with AsyncStorage, as I have a screen from where user can change in-app language independent from the device. Now the problem is, how to update my DrawerNavigator's titles?
[image: app menu]

Here is also how my navigation & stacks are configured(note I change language inside Settings):

```
/**
 * React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  ScrollView
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator, TabNavigator, DrawerNavigator, DrawerItems } from 'react-navigation'
var Home = require('./Home')
var Info = require('./Info')
var Settings = require('./Settings')
var Help = require('./Help')
var Groups = require('./Groups')
var Details = require('./Details')

export default class Stryn extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View/>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  menu_icon: {
    width: 24,
    height: 24,
    tintColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)'
  },
  menu_container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(112,98,89,1)'
  },
  menu_title: {
    paddingTop: 50,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 20,
  }
})

const Stack = {
    Home: {
        screen: Home
    },
  Info: {
    screen: Info
  },
  Settings: {
    screen: Settings
  },
  Help: {
    screen: Help
  },
  Groups: {
    screen: Groups
  },
  Details: {
    screen: Details
  }
};

const DrawerRoutes = {
    FirstViewStack: {
        name: 'FirstViewStack',
        screen: StackNavigator(Stack, { initialRouteName: 'Home' }),
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Home',
      drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <Image
          source={require('./static/img/home.png')}
          style={[styles.menu_icon]}
        />
      ),
    },
    },
  SecondViewStack: {
        name: 'SecondViewStack',
        screen: StackNavigator(Stack, { initialRouteName: 'Info' }),
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Info',
      drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <Image
          source={require('./static/img/information.png')}
          style={[styles.menu_icon]}
        />
      ),
    },
    },
  ThirdViewStack: {
        name: 'ThirdViewStack',
        screen: StackNavigator(Stack, { initialRouteName: 'Settings' }),
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Settings',
      drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <Image
          source={require('./static/img/settings.png')}
          style={[styles.menu_icon]}
        />
      ),
    },
    },
};

const DrawerConfig = {
  contentComponent: props =>
    <View style={styles.menu_container}>
      <Text style={styles.menu_title}>Stryn</Text>
      <ScrollView style={{backgroundColor:'rgba(112,98,89,1)'}}>
        <DrawerItems {...props} labelStyle={{color:'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)'}} />
      </ScrollView>
    </View>,
  drawerPosition: 'left',
}

const RootNavigator =
    StackNavigator({
        Drawer: {
            name: 'Drawer',
            screen: DrawerNavigator(
                DrawerRoutes,
        DrawerConfig
            ),
        },
        ...Stack
    },
        {
            headerMode: 'none'
        }
    );

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Stryn', () => RootNavigator);
```

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using your own component for the drawer, which you are using in `DrawerConfig`. Since you have full control of your `DrawerItems`, you can just pass your `LocalizedStrings` to them, and use a key from the `LocalizedStrings` as the text in the each item.

**Addendum**

The comments asked how to update the language after initial wake up, or generally how to update the menus. Well, that depends on where you're keeping the current language, and how you're passing that to the drawer component.

You could, for example, keep the language in a Redux store (or some other state keeping mechanism), and then pass that to the root navigator using `screenProps`. That way the component can read the language from its props and call up the correct translations. See [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html) for more info on `screenProps`.

Comment: But how to update it after initial wake up? Maybe using singleton for the localizations or some other approach?

Comment: the point is, after the lang changes, next refresh should be able to update the menu items with the changed langage right ? How to do that